# Show exact timing on SQL query

Tags: mysql

When I do the following statement, I only get two decimal places on the output:

```
> select * from table;
98 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How would I get more precision on this (without using `SHOW PROFILES`). For example, it would be nice to see:

```
> select * from table;
98 rows in set (0.001837884 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man what you want is a bit hardcore. You need to customize the nice_time() on mysql core, then you can set the decimal places you wanted.

There is a another question like this on stackoverflow, you can access this link to further information:
[How do I see high-precision query times in mysql command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102744/how-do-i-see-high-precision-query-times-in-mysql-command-line)